# add formGroup with teg input on click and validate values input, save, Angular2

Tags: angular, validation, formgroups

**How can I validate the data after I click the add car button and before I click the save button**              I thought   it should be created EventEmitter, but it does not work as it should.

I post parts of the application files___________________________________________________________________.

comp.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" value="{{owner.id}}"  hidden formControlName="id">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="mb-3 form-group" [ngClass]="{invalid: form.get('FirstName')?.touched && form.get('FirstName')?.invalid}">
      <label for="FirstName" class="form-label">FirstName</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" value="{{owner.FirstName}}" formControlName="FirstName">
</div>
</div>
  <form [formGroup]="formCar" (submit)="submit()">
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row"  *ngIf="hidden == false">
          <div class="mb-3 form-group" [ngClass]="{invalid: form.get('number')?.touched && form.get('number')?.invalid}">
            <label for="number" class="form-label">number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" value="" formControlName="number">
          
          </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="addCar($event)">add car</button>
      </form>

    <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="form.invalid || submitted">save</button>
</form>
```

comp.ts...

```
addCarElement = new EventEmitter<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private ownerService: OwnerService, private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.subscription = route.params.subscribe(params => this.params.owner_id = params.id);
    console.log(this.params);


    this.form = this.fb.group({
      id: [this.params.owner_id, [Validators.required]],
      FirstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
    }); }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.SubOwner = this.ownerService.getOwnerById(this.params.owner_id).subscribe(data => {
        this.owner = data;
        console.log(this.owner);
      },
      error => {
        this.error = error.message;
        console.log(error);
      }, );

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.form = this.fb.group({
        id: [this.params.owner_id, [Validators.required]],
        FirstName: [this.owner.FirstName, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      });
    }, 1000);

  //  if ( this.addCarElement === true) {
    //  console.log('ttty');
                              this.formCar = this.fb.group({
        number: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(8), Validators.pattern('^[ABCEHIKMOPTX]{2}\d{4}(?<!0{4})[ABCEHIKMOPTX]{2}$')]],
      });
   // }
  }

  submit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    const car: Car = {
      number: this.formCar.value.number,
    };
    const car1 = [car];

    const owner: Owner = {
     id: this.form.value.id,
      FirstName: this.form.value.FirstName,
      cars:  this.owner.cars?.concat(car1)
    };
    console.log(this.owner.cars?.concat(car1));
    console.log(owner);
    this.ownerService.editOwner(owner).subscribe( () => this.router.navigate(['']));
  }

  addCar(event: Event) {
    this.hidden = false;
    this.addCarElement.emit(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your problem may be that you have a form inside a form. The outer form is not going to validate when you do something to the inner form. One thing you could do is mark the form as touched so any validation messages will appear.

```
addCar(event: Event) {
    if(this.formCar.invalid) {
         this.formCar.markAllAsTouched();
         return;
    }
    this.hidden = false;
    this.addCarElement.emit(true);
}
```